# Divide two counts in one selection (with date_trunc)

Tags: postgresql

I want to divide two `Count`s in a single query, but the `DATE_TRUNC` causes some issues

So far I have a query in postgre looking like this:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', "Date") as date, 
COUNT(*) as AllTransactions,
COUNT(*) filter (where "State"='ACCEPTED') as Accepted,
FROM "Acceptance_Report"
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

It returns this:

| Date | AllTransactions | Accepted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 930 | 647 |
| 2019-02-01 | 840 | 589 |

Now I need to get the percentage, so it should be `Accepted`/`AllTransactions`*100

I understand that I could create another table and use `INSERT` , but I feel like there is another easy way to do it in a single query.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to divide them, repeat the expressions. But it's important to convert one of the counts to a numeric value, otherwise it would result in an integer division (where 1/5 yields `0`)

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', "Date") as date, 
       COUNT(*) as AllTransactions,
       COUNT(*) filter (where "State"='ACCEPTED') as Accepted,
       COUNT(*)::numeric  / COUNT(*) filter (where "State"='ACCEPTED') as pct
FROM "Acceptance_Report"
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

If you don't want to repeat the expressions, you can use a derived table:

```
select "date", 
       alltransactions, 
       accepted, 
       alltransactions::numeric / accepted as pct
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', "Date") as date, 
         COUNT(*) as AllTransactions,
         COUNT(*) filter (where "State"='ACCEPTED') as Accepted
  FROM "Acceptance_Report"
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1
) t
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I added *100 to the line for percents, but other than that the solution is perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AVG()` aggregate function over the boolean expression `"State" = 'ACCEPTED'` converted to 1 for `true` and 0 for `false`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', "Date") AS date, 
       COUNT(*) AS AllTransactions,
       COUNT(*) filter (where "State" = 'ACCEPTED') AS Accepted,
       100 * AVG(("State" = 'ACCEPTED')::int) AS percentage
FROM "Acceptance_Report"
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/A1Y4hAo2).